# Hide SO sitemap on Google Search result

Tags: support, google

Just stumbled upon this when searching ["could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure ksoap2" on Google](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=could+not+establish+trust+relationship+for+the+SSL%2FTLS+secure+channel+the+remote+certificate+is+invalid+according+to+the+validation+procedure+ksoap2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=1Ww_VOEzicTgAoW7gPgH), there is a link to https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap-questions-0.xml

> [image: google search result]

However, when I clicked it, I got SO's "Page Not Found".

So my questions:

- <s>What is this file and what is it for?</s>
- Seeing that there is a text that says "2014-10-11" tells me that it is quite up-to-date, but why I cannot open it on the browser? (answered on MSE: [Does Stack Overflow have a sitemap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19805/does-stackoverflow-have-a-sitemap) and its relevant links)
- Is it possible to hide it from Google Search?

(Changed from "remove" to "hide" due to bad word choice)

---

Comment: Search engines and crawlers *explicitly make use of* the sitemap; that is *why it exists*. Blocking access to the sitemap would be a very bad idea...

Comment: Edited to clarify. I *didn't* mean to remove sitemap, just want to hide it. However, if it's outside of SE scope, let me know so that I can delete it.

Comment: @MarcGravell This should get a [meta-tag:status-bydesign] tag, I guess?

Comment: It is *not* by design. It's just [a Google bug, rather than a Stack Overflow bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103946/why-do-google-present-links-to-sitemap-xml-files), @Stijn.